# JS: How is this mathematic operation called?

Tags: javascript, math, colors

I just stumbled over this line in a color converter, but have no clue whatsoever it does neither do I know the name. Do you know?

```js
// `hsvToRgb`
// Converts an HSV color value to RGB.
// *Assumes:* h is contained in [0, 1] or [0, 360] and s and v are contained in [0, 1] or [0, 100]
// *Returns:* { r, g, b } in the set [0, 255]
 function hsvToRgb(h, s, v) {

    h = bound01(h, 360) * 6;
    s = bound01(s, 100);
    v = bound01(v, 100);

    var i = Math.floor(h),
        f = h - i,
        p = v * (1 - s),
        q = v * (1 - f * s),
        t = v * (1 - (1 - f) * s),
        mod = i % 6,
        r = [v, q, p, p, t, v][mod],    // <-- It's this line
        g = [t, v, v, q, p, p][mod],
        b = [p, p, t, v, v, q][mod];

    return { r: r * 255, g: g * 255, b: b * 255 };
}
```

The original file: [TinyColor.js](https://github.com/bgrins/TinyColor/blob/master/tinycolor.js#L488)

Comment: hue, saturation, brightness to red green blue.

Comment: color conversion. more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Converting_to_RGB, it is the part (R1, G1, B1) = ...

Comment: Simple array, and bracket notation to read array value at index `mod`. Nothing unusual.

Comment: Oh I see, it's a dynamic created array and then the nth-element (based on mod) is choosen.
Had too much math before my eyes :D

Comment: @SörenKlein To expand a little: It's called an array literal, and it is accessed immediately via bracket notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HSV (hue, saturation, value) can be visualized as a "hexcone", a hexagonal cone (see http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Graphics/Colors/HSVhexcone.gif). To convert the hue to a RGB-style color, the code first determines which of the 6 "slices" of the hexagon it falls in (`mod = i % 6`). So `mod` is a slice-number, integer from 0 to 5. The line you indicated (and the next two) looks up RGB values from those arrays depending on which slice the hue is in. So if the hue value has us in slice number 1, then RGB will be set to (q, v, p).